# If I localize my iPhone App, (Description Language) But don't change my app, will it be rejected?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I want to add local languages for the description of my app, and so I made a new version just so I could Localize the description. However, I did not change any of my app to be location-dependent (It's just english, and it's a rather simple resistance-color code calculator app without much text, and operates on the basis of color-codedness.) Will my app be rejected for failing to truly "localize", per se? Is this a stringent guideline or is it okay to just change the app store description language?

Comment: I think you'd be fine. If you wanted to protect yourself you could mention in the localized description that the app itself is in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app should not be rejected. I've done this. My app is mostly numbers which is universal. I've translated descriptions to 6 languages and the app is in the app store just fine.

Comment: Awesome. Mine is very similar-along with color names, there are clear, concise colors for each button. Just curious, have you noticed any change in sales from localizing descriptions?

Comment: Yes, generally what it does (in my opinion) is allow for better searching in other stores, but you will get more customers who speak english anyway. Put simply, someone will search the app store in italian, but still use your app if it's in english and they speak it, or if it's numbered/colered and thus universal.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if Apple will reject you on that basis or not.  But doing something like that could anger your customers, and I wouldn't blame them.  I would suggest that you either localize everything, including the content, or localize nothing.  Misleading your customers is not the path to long-term success.

Comment: The app photos clearly show the several (very few) words in the application in English. Im not concerned people will be mislead, more that I'm in line with the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mislead your users. Your users are your greatest allies or enemies, depending on your attitude. If you don't respect them, they won't like you.

If you want to make a localization, create a support for multilinguality and you can add languages later on. Also, in my opinion your users should be able to choose the language they want to use your app in. As a default you can choose the language of the region. However, it's rude to localize by location and not letting the users to change their language. If you show respect towards your users you will have greater chance of success.

Comment: To add to that -- if there really is very little text to localize in the app, why don't you just have your translator translate that text along with the description? That way there's nothing misleading about it at all.